# Can't install Eel with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, eel

I wanted to use auto-py-to-exe, and it needed Eel, because of the graphical interface.
whenever I try to install this happens:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\regok\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\regok\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\regok\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ebqi0iw2\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools >= 40.8.0' wheel 'Cython >= 3.0a5' 'cffi >= 1.12.3 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'greenlet >= 0.4.17 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

It always does that, even when I run the cmd as an administrator.
If you don't want to search here's the for the py file thing

> https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

I'm trying to use this command: pip install auto-py-to-exe
I'm new to this so please help me!

Comment: Works for me, but maybe [you should ask the package developers](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe/issues)?

Comment: Unfortunately, the error message isn't that helpful. Are you able to get a full error output and post the full stacktrace?